# Similar to triangle (and reverse triangle) inequality, proof that $||x|-|y|| ≤ |x+y|$

Tags: number-theory

Note that left side is part of reverse triangle inequality $$||x|-|y||≤|x - y|$$
And the right side is part of triangle inequality $$|x+y|≤|x|+|y|$$

I tried to solve it in two different ways, but I could not get the final answer in any of them. First:
As $|x-y|=|x+(-y)|$, I've applied the triangle inequality: $$|x+(-y)|≤|x|+|(-y)|$$
If I could define $| y | = | -y |$ (can I do this?), we would have $$|x+(-y)|≤|x|+|y|$$ 
In reverse triangle inequality, we have that $$||x|-|y||≤|x-y| $$ $$ ||x|-|y||≤|x|+|y|$$ $$||x|-|y||≤|x+(-y)|=|x-y|$$
Is this right? 
I don't know if I can do this.

The other way that I tried to solve was:
$$||x|-|y||≤|x+y|$$
$$||x|-|y||≤|x|+|y|$$
$$||x|-|y||≤|x|+|y|$$
Let $|x|-|y|=t$,
$$|t|≤|x|+|y|$$
Now we have
$$|x|≥|t|-|y|$$
And applying the reverse triangle inequality again, we have
$$|x|≥|t-y|$$

But I think this isn't the right way to solve the problem...

Comment: From $|x-y|+|y|ge |x|$ it follows that $|x-y|\ge |x|-|y|$. Reversing the role of $x$ and $y$ we get $|x-y|=|y-x|\ge |x|-|y|$. Combining, $|x-y|\ge ||x|-|y||$. Now substitute $-y$ in place of $y$ and you get your result.

Comment: Just replace $y$ with $-y$ in reverse triangle inequailty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the triangle inequalty to $y = x + y - x$ and $x = y + x - y$ and use the fact that $|y - x| = |x - y|.$